# Rewrite only a specific file using MOD_REWRITE

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a file that can be reached using multiple paths:

http://mydomain.com/portal1/movie.swf
http://mydomain.com/portal2/movie.swf
http://mydomain.com/portal1/substep/movie.swf
etc.

I want a rewrite rule to get this specific file from the following path:

http://mydomain.com/movie.swf

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in  .htaccess in your main folder:

```
RewriteRule ^portal.*movie\.swf$ /movie.swf [L]
```

(backlash before the dot added after Gumbos comment. +1)

Comment: I don't want to specify a rule for every possible path. Can I rewrite alle movie.swf's to /movie.swf using 1 rule?

Comment: Never mind - your solution worked. I used RewriteRule ^.*/movie.swf$ /movie.swf [L]

Comment: Don’t forget to escape the `.` character.